# Boisik package \textfont undefined in MikTeX 2.9

Tags: symbols

The following does not work in MikTeX 2.9.5870 64-bit + (`pdflatex` or `xelatex`):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{boisik}
\begin{document}
$\smile$
\end{document}
```

The error is

```
\textfont 4 is undefined (character ) $\smile$
```

Many other symbols bring a similar error. Running `pdflatex` from the command-line provides more information. The problem is in `miktex-mf.exe`, which triggers an error in `bskletters-o.mf`:

```
! The paths don't intersect.
```

What is going on?

Comment: I unfortunately can't help too much, but it works just fine on my end; TeX Live 2015 on Mac, with TeXShop 3.61. Hopefully that will help pinpoint the issue!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a recently introduced bug in MikTeX, present at least in 2.9.5870. The example works after installing MikTeX 2.9.5550 (using the currently latest ProTeXT installer).

#### A hack to make it work

The example also works when you start from MikTeX 2.9.5550, and then update all packages *except* `miktex-metafont-bin` and `miktex-mfware-bin`. I did not try to narrow it down whether one these could also be updated.

Unfortunately, this puts the MikTeX executables into an inconsistent state, in that this example

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{apl}
\begin{document}
\SS
\end{document}
```

triggers an *operating-system error* where the function `WideCharToUTF8` cannot be found from the dynamic-link library `miktex-mf.exe`. On the positive side, all other packages seem to work --- in the sense that I can generate the images of almost every symbol from almost every package in the Latex Comprehensive Symbol List.

So this should only be tried  as a last resort.

Comment: Reported the [bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2475/).